# Firing events at a 1 year interval

Tags: android

I am trying to make a birthday app in android. The app should sound a alarm at a specified date, every year, on the same day.The problem is that there are many methods in android for doing the same. Like using class AlarmManager, or using the System.currentime function. And there is method using handle. Which is the best way to implement my program. I dont want that the app never lets the cpu sleep, like the AlarmManager. Whats the most efficient way to achieve this type of task?

Comment: What about programmatically using the Calendar? It would be too stressful to keep a full Alarm Service on for an year. Google policy for AlarmManager is very strict.

Comment: check daily if some one from database has a bd "today" ... Daily interval is ok ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a service class and add it to your manifest, the service every working in background without opening the app. Create a Thread with timing to birthday.
This is all the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html